# Phaser 3 How to Access and Affect Player in Collision between 2 Objects Not Involving Player

Tags: javascript, typescript, phaser-framework

I am trying to create a grappling hook in Phaser 3. I can successfully shoot the grappling hook at an upward angle away from the player. I need to get the player to move towards the grappling hook when the grappling hook reaches its destination. The problem is that I can't access the player object in my `Spawner.ts` file to move the player object. If I could access the player object I could set the velocity at the moment of collision between the grappling hook and the level.

This is the relevant code in the `Spawner.ts` file:

```
import { Actor } from "./Actor";
import { Level } from "./Level";
import { Layer } from "./shared";
import { Projectile } from "./Projectile/Projectile";
import { GameScene } from "../scenes/GameScene";
import { Player } from "./Player";
import { GrapplingHook } from "./GrapplingHook";

interface ActorConstructor {
    new (scene: Phaser.Scene, x: number, y: number): Actor;
}

interface GrapplingHookContructor {
    new (scene: GameScene, x: number, y: number): GrapplingHook;
}

export class Spawner {
    private projectiles: Phaser.GameObjects.Group;
    private actors: Phaser.GameObjects.Group;
    private grapplinghooks: Phaser.GameObjects.Group;

    constructor(private scene: GameScene, private level: Level) {
        this.actors = this.scene.add.group();
        this.setUpGrapplingHooks();
    }

    spawnDynamic<T extends ActorConstructor>(
        layer: Layer,
        type: T
    ): Phaser.GameObjects.Group {
        const objects = this.level.getObjects(layer);
        const instances = objects.map((e) => new type(this.scene, e.x, e.y));
        const group = this.scene.add.group(instances);
        this.level.addGroundCollision(group);
        return group;
    }

    spawnPlayer(layer: Layer): Player {
        const player = this.spawnDynamic(
            layer,
            Player
        ).getChildren()[0] as Player;

        this.actors.add(player);

        return player;
    }

    spawnGrapplingHook<T extends GrapplingHookContructor>(
        type: T,
        x: number,
        y: number,
        xVelocity = 0,
        yVelocity = 0
    ): void {
        const grapplinghook = new type(this.scene, x, y);
        this.grapplinghooks.add(grapplinghook);
        grapplinghook.body.setVelocity(xVelocity, yVelocity);
        grapplinghook.body.setCollideWorldBounds(true, undefined, undefined, true);
    }

    destroyGrapplingHooks() {
        this.grapplinghooks.getChildren().map(child => child.destroy());
    }

    private getObjectData(
        object: Phaser.Types.Tilemaps.TiledObject
    ): Record<string, unknown> {
        const props = object.properties as unknown;
        const data: Record<string, unknown> = {};

        if (props instanceof Array) {
            props.forEach((p: { name: string; value: unknown }) => {
                data[p.name] = p.value;
            });
        }

        return data;
    }

    private setUpGrapplingHooks() {
        this.grapplinghooks = this.scene.add.group();
        this.grapplinghooks.runChildUpdate = true;
        this.level.addGroundCollision(this.grapplinghooks, (grapplinghook) =>
            (grapplinghook as GrapplingHook).onLevelCollide()
        );

        this.scene.physics.add.collider(
            this.grapplinghooks,
            this.level.getLayer(Layer.Bricks),
            (grapplinghook) => (grapplinghook as Projectile).onLevelCollide()
        );

        this.scene.physics.add.collider(
            this.grapplinghooks,
            this.actors,
            (grapplinghook, entity) => {
                (grapplinghook as Projectile).onCollide(entity as Actor);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

This is the relevant code in the `Player.ts` file:

```
import { TILE_WIDTH } from "./shared";
import type { GameScene } from "../scenes/GameScene";
import { Actor } from "./Actor";
import { Assets } from "./shared";
import { GrapplingHook } from "./GrapplingHook";

interface Controls {
    Left: Phaser.Input.Keyboard.Key;
    Right: Phaser.Input.Keyboard.Key;
    Jump: Phaser.Input.Keyboard.Key;
    ThrowGrapplingHook: Phaser.Input.Keyboard.Key;
}

export class Player extends Actor {
    protected readonly totalHitPoints = 3;
    protected readonly immunityAfterDamageTime: number = 1000;

    private controls: Controls;

    constructor(scene: GameScene, x: number, y: number) {
        super(scene, x, y, Assets[Assets.Player], 1);

        // controls
        this.controls = {
            Left: scene.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.A),
            Right: scene.input.keyboard.addKey(
                Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.D
            ),
            Jump: scene.input.keyboard.addKey(
                Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.SPACE
            ),
            ThrowGrapplingHook: scene.input.keyboard.addKey(
                Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.H
            )
        };
    }

    /**
     * Throws a projectile at a given angle and force
     * @param time The current game time
     * @param angle The angle to throw the projectile; Should be a value between -90 (straight down) and 90 (straight up)
     * @param force What velocity to throw the projectile at
     */

    protected throwGrapplingHook(time: number, angle: number, force: number) {
        if (angle > 90 || angle < -90) {
            throw `throwProjectile(angle) must be between -90 and 90; current value: ${angle}`;
        }

        this.lastProjectileThrowTime = time;

        let x = this.body.x;
        if (this.flipX) {
            x = x + TILE_WIDTH;
        }

        // calculate the x and y force based on angle and total force
        // angle: 0 -> x velocity at 100%, y at 0%
        // angle: 90 -> x velocity at 0%, y at 100%

        const percentYForce = angle / 90;
        const yVelocity = force * percentYForce * -1;
        let xVelocity = force - Math.abs(yVelocity);

        if (this.body.velocity.x < 0) {
            xVelocity *= -1;
        }

        this.scene.spawner.spawnGrapplingHook(
            GrapplingHook,
            x,
            this.body.y,
            xVelocity,
            yVelocity
        );
    }

    protected onUpdate(): void {
        if (!this.active) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the relevant code from the `GrapplingHook.ts` file:

```
import type { Actor } from "./Actor";
import { Assets } from "./shared";

export class GrapplingHook extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite {
    declare body: Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body;

    constructor(scene: Phaser.Scene, x: number, y: number) {
        super(scene, x, y, Assets[Assets.Projectiles], 1);

        scene.add.existing(this);
        scene.physics.add.existing(this);
        this.body.setAllowGravity(false);

        this.body
            .setSize(this.body.width, this.body.height - 20, true)
            .updateCenter()
    }

    onCollide(target: Actor): void {
        this.destroy();
    }

    onLevelCollide(): void {
        this.setVelocity(0,0);
    }

    update(): void {
        this.flipX = this.body.velocity.x >= 0
    }
}
```

As it is now, the code successfully throws the grappling hook but I can't actually move the player after it collides with the level. I haven't even looked into how to move the player ***towards*** the actually collided grappling hook, as a proof of concept I just want to nudge the player forward when the collision happens.
My instincts are to change the `onLevelCollide` function in `GrapplingHook.ts` to:

```
onLevelCollide(player: Player): void {
        player.setVelocityX(100);
        this.setVelocity(0,0);
    }
```

And then add a player object into `onLevelCollide()` when it's called in `Spawner.ts` but I can't seem to access the player in `Spawner.ts`. How would I pass the player object into onLevelCollide or possibly work around this problem another way?

Again I am trying to move the player on the grappling hook's collision with the level. If you need me to post more code or clarify let me know.

Comment: The call `spawnGrapplingHook` already accepts some parameters. What is preventing you to pass the player as an additional parameter and then pass the player into the GrapplingHook constructor as well?

Comment: I tried this in the answer below. It compiles but I still can't get it to move my player on collision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because I was interested, on how I would approach this problem myself, I adapted *(I stripped the most stuff out, that is not really needed)* this phaser example ([First Game](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/games/firstgame/part10)) to acomplish the grappling hook mechanic.

I'm just sharing it, because it is a small working example covering the key task:

- shooting the hook
- managing the velocity, before / during / after the *hook-action*
- pulling the player towards the hook

*Yes, it is only javascript without classes(and ...), but it still illustrates the main point nicely (I think).*

> **Controls:**
>
> - left mouse button: shoot "hook"
> - <kbd>left</kbd> / <kbd>Right</kbd> : move/walk player (animation was removed)
> - <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> retract grappling hook

```js
var config = {
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        physics: {
            default: 'arcade',
            arcade: {
                gravity: { y: 150 }
            }
        },
        scene: {
            preload: preload,
            create: create,
            update: update
        }
    };

    var player;
    var platforms;
    var cursors;

    // basic Hook Object
    var hook = {
        isPulling: false,
        isAttached: false,
        speed: 500,
        set display(value){
          this.gameObject.visible = value;
          this.ropeGameObject.visible = value;
        }
    }

    var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

    function preload ()
    {
        this.load.image('ground', 'https://labs.phaser.io/src/games/firstgame/assets/platform.png');
        this.load.image('star', 'https://labs.phaser.io/src/games/firstgame/assets/star.png');
        this.load.spritesheet('dude', 'https://labs.phaser.io/src/games/firstgame/assets/dude.png', { frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 48 });
    }

    function create ()
    {
    
        let txt = this.add.text(0, 20, '> click mouse to shoot hook\n\t>> press "shift" to pull');
        platforms = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
        platforms.create(200, 310, 'ground');
        platforms.create(200, -10, 'ground');
        platforms.create(400, 100, 'ground').setScale(.5).refreshBody();
        platforms.create(50, 175, 'ground').setScale(.5).refreshBody();
        
        // Setup Hook Rope
        hook.ropeGameObject = this.add.line(0,0, 0,0, 10,10, 0xff0000).setOrigin(0);
        
        // Setup Hook
        hook.gameObject = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 450, 'star').setScale(.3);
        hook.gameObject.body.allowGravity = false;
        
        // Hide Hook
        hook.display = false;
        
        // Setup Hook Collision
        this.physics.add.collider(hook.gameObject, platforms, grab);
        
        player = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 450, 'dude',4).setScale(.75);
        player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
        player.setBounce(0.2);
        this.physics.add.collider(player, platforms);
        
        // Setup User Controls
        cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
        this.input.on('pointerdown', shootHook, this);
    }

    function grab(hk, platform){
        hook.gameObject.setVelocity(0);
        hook.isAttached = true;
    }

    function shootHook(pointer){
        if(!hook.isPulling){
            let velocity = new Phaser.Math.Vector2(pointer.x - player.x, pointer.y - player.y)
                .normalize()
                .scale(hook.speed);
            hook.gameObject.x = player.x;
            hook.gameObject.y = player.y;
            hook.display = true;
            hook.isAttached = false;  
            hook.gameObject.setVelocity(velocity.x, velocity.y);
        }
    }

    function updateHookRope(){
        hook.ropeGameObject.setTo(player.x, player.y,hook.gameObject.x,hook.gameObject.y);
    }

    function update ()
    {
        updateHookRope();
        if(hook.isAttached && cursors.shift.isDown){
            hook.isPulling = true;
            let pullVelocity = new Phaser.Math.Vector2( hook.gameObject.x - player.x, hook.gameObject.y - player.y)
                .normalize()
                .scale(hook.speed / 1.5);
            player.setVelocity(pullVelocity.x, pullVelocity.y);
            
        } else if(hook.isPulling) { // Hook was released so remove it
          if(hook.isAttached){
             hook.isAttached = false;
             hook.display = false;
           }
           hook.isPulling = !player.body.touching.down;
        }

        if(hook.isPulling){
            return;
        }

        if (cursors.left.isDown) {
            player.setVelocityX(-160);
        }
        else if (cursors.right.isDown) {
            player.setVelocityX(160);
        }
        else {
            player.setVelocityX(0);
        }

    }
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Refactor the `GrapplingHook` constructor to accept the player too

In `Spawner.ts`

```
interface GrapplingHookContructor {
    // refactor the constructor to accept a player as well
    new (scene: GameScene, player: Player, x: number, y: number): GrapplingHook;
}
```

In `GrapplingHook.ts` do the same, add a player property and assign to it the player from the constructor parameter

```
export class GrapplingHook extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite {
    declare body: Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body;

    private player: Player; // add this

    // refactor the constructor to accept a player as well
    constructor(scene: Phaser.Scene, player: Player, x: number, y: number) {
        super(scene, x, y, Assets[Assets.Projectiles], 1);
        
        this.player = player; // add this
```

Refactor the `spawnGrapplingHook` call to accept the player and pass the player to the `GrapplingHook` constructor

```
spawnGrapplingHook<T extends GrapplingHookContructor>(
        type: T,
        player: Player, // add this
        x: number,
        y: number,
        xVelocity = 0,
        yVelocity = 0
    ): void {
        // pass the player as a parameter
        const grapplinghook = new type(this.scene, player, x, y);
        // ...
    }
```

In `GrapplingHook.ts`

```
onLevelCollide(): void {
    // do the math here to move the player
    this.player.setVelocityX(100);
    this.setVelocity(0,0);
}
```

Another option that might work for you is to keep a reference to the player in `Spawner.ts`, set it when `spawnPlayer(layer: Layer): Player` is called. Then use `this.scene.spawner.player` to access it anywhere else you need it?

Comment: Awww so close. I made the changes that you posted above and it compiles but it still doesn't move my character on collision. Btw, I'm assuming on that last line adding `this.player.setVelocityX(100);` to `onLevelCollide` you meant to change that in `GrapplingHook.ts` instead of `Spawner.ts`. I will try you're second suggestion of referencing player when `spawnPlayer(layer: Layer): Player` is called. How would I do this though? I tried setting it with `this.player = player` after adding `public player = Player` to the constructor but it won't compile.

Comment: I printed out the "player" object in this function in `GrapplingHook.ts`  
```
onLevelCollide(): void {
        console.log(this.player)
        this.player.setVelocityY(500);
        this.setVelocity(0,0);
    }
```

 https://imgur.com/a/65q1fQw  
  
This is the player object explanded:
https://imgur.com/a/3ClWg9y
https://imgur.com/a/OCOiep5
@Ma3x

Comment: @ChristianOConnor why don't you update your question, with the information in the comments. It is easier to write and read. :) You could check the **method** where your are implementing _the player movement_. Since in some implementations, on each update loop the `velocity`it set to `0` if no key is pressed.

Comment: @ChristianOConnor Yeah I meant in `GrapplingHook.ts`, I fixed the typo in my answer. If the 2nd option that you tried doesn't compile, you get a compiler error, fix what the compiler error tells you about. I assume you did not declare a player variable in the `Spawner` class. Also if just the movement does not work, it means your other code is affecting it, but the player reference was passed correctly to the place in code where you needed it.